# load specific images from Parse into UIPageViewController : SWIFT

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a test method to achieve a rule and it's working fine. So basically my code is looking for images and all images are of type jpg and named as AnswerXImageY.jpg where X could be any integer and Y is always 5 or less. Then I am deleting the extra objects from array so that it can display only the number of images found on the PageViewController. 
This method is working fine.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AnswerDetailsViewController : UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var pageViewController : UIPageViewController!

    var image1: String!
    var image2: String!
    var image3: String!
    var image4: String!
    var image5: String!

    var image1Int : Int!
    var scoreInt : Int!
    var scoreSilverInt: Int!

    var pageImages:NSMutableArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        image1 = "Answer" + "\(image1Int)" + "Image1.jpg"
        image2 = "Answer" + "\(image1Int)" + "Image2.jpg"
        image3 = "Answer" + "\(image1Int)" + "Image3.jpg"
        image4 = "Answer" + "\(image1Int)" + "Image4.jpg"
        image5 = "Answer" + "\(image1Int)" + "Image5.jpg"

        self.pageImages = [image1,image2 ,image3,image4,image5 ]


        var path1 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Answer" + "\(image1Int)" + "Image1", ofType: "jpg")
        var path2 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Answer" + "\(image1Int)" + "Image2", ofType: "jpg")
        var path3 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Answer" + "\(image1Int)" + "Image3", ofType: "jpg")
        var path4 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Answer" + "\(image1Int)" + "Image4", ofType: "jpg")
        var path5 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Answer" + "\(image1Int)" + "Image5", ofType: "jpg")


        if (path1 == nil)
        {
            self.pageImages.removeObject(image1)
        }

        if (path2 == nil)
        {
            self.pageImages.removeObject(image2)
        }

        if (path3 == nil)
        {
            self.pageImages.removeObject(image3)
        }

        if (path4 == nil)
        {
            self.pageImages.removeObject(image4)
        }

        if (path5 == nil)
        {
            self.pageImages.removeObject(image5)
        }

        if (self.pageImages.count == 0)
        {
            self.pageImages = ["NoImageAvailable.jpg"]
        }

        self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self


        var startvc = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController

        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startvc)

        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 60)

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

           }
```

I now want to upload the images from Parse instead of using my assets.
I have the following code which is incomplete and pulling only 1 image. Please help me figure out how should I look for specific images e.g. "Answer5ImageY" and store them in array and display them in PageViewController. Thank you a lot in advance.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

class UserSettingsViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var animation2 : UIImageView!

    var competitionArray:NSMutableArray = []

    var fragenImages = [PFFile] ()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadImages()

    }

    func loadImages()


    {

        var query = PFQuery(className: "EasyQuizImages")

        query.orderByAscending("AnswerImages")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects,error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let imagesobjects = objects as! [PFObject]

                for object : PFObject in objects as! [PFObject] {
                    let image = object["AnswerImages"] as! PFFile

                    image.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                        //let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageFile)

                        let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                            self.animation2.image = finalimage
                            println("Success")


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't look to pull just one image, it looks to pull and download all of them. The reason you only see one is that you're always putting the images into a single image view so you see the last one downloaded (and may see some flickering as the images change over in between downloads).

You don't describe your data store on parse, but you should consider:

1. How many image objects you have and if you should be adding a filter to the query or getting all objects
2. Storing all of the objects and then locally finding the correct one to download the file for
3. Caching the files you have downloaded so you don't need to download them again

In any case you should split your code up so that you query the objects and store them, then get the image files and store them. This store should probably be in a dictionary with a key for the answer and image number so you can easily check if you have the one you want and get it.

Comment: How should I write a query to filter the images but with names? Class: "EasyQuizImages" Column: "AnswerImages" Name of image file uploaded : "Answer1Image3.jpg" Thanks

Comment: You can't filter on the image file name, your `EasyQuizImages` class should have some columns for the answer and maybe image numbers so you can filter on them in the query